# Can a for loop be timed?

Tags: python-3.x, windows

```py
from ast import Break
import pyautogui as pat
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard

# time.sleep(3)

# print(pat.position())

    pat.click(x=712, y=1052, duration=1)
    pat.click(x=1108, y=917)
    
    file = open('peanut.txt', 'r').readlines()
    
    for i in file:
        pat.typewrite(i, interval=0.1)
        pat.press('enter')
```

How do I time the for loop to stop or command the loop to stop by pressing a key?

I tried using the keyboard module but I could only find a simulation of the 'esc' key but I cannot seem to figure out what module would allow me to physically press a key to quit the program??  Any help would be fantastic.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you can bind any key to stop loop

```
import keyboard
number=1
while True:
    number=number+1
    print(number)
    keyboard.wait("escape")
```

try this code
this code will print a number and will wait escape, if escape is pressed will print another number infinitely
or you can do this

```
import keyboard
number=1
while True:
    number=number+1
    print(number)
    if keyboard.is_pressed("escape"):
        break
    else:
        pass
def AfterLoopWhile(): 
    """This code can't execute if the loop isn't break (Sorry for my 
    english)"""
    print("Stopped the loop")
AfterLoopWhile() "If the loop is break, execute the function AfterLoopWhile
```

to stop the loop
or you can quit if escape is pressed

```
import keyboard
number=1
while True:
    number=number+1
    print(number)
    if keyboard.is_pressed("escape"):
        exit()
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response I will leverage the information that you gave me and try to make my program work!  Cheers!

Comment: I'm glad it helped you, if you can, upvote my answer